# SendBroadcast for refreshing gallery

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-broadcast

I am developing a Xamarin app which retrieves info from a DB, takes/chooses photos and uploads them to a remote server, then it can display the images from the remote server.

The user can delete them by tapping on and pressing a button and download the images from the remote server to the local device.

Everything works without fine, but when I download one image it is not found in the gallery, whereas I can open it from the file explorer.

When I reboot the phone, the image appears also in the gallery.

I found this way to achieve the result:

```
private void GalleryRefresh(string file_name)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File("file://" + Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads));
                Android.Net.Uri contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(f);             
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
                this.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                SendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + file_name)));
            }
        }
```

**But I am struggling with SendBroadcast, I do not underestand if I have to implement or initialize it somewhere in my solution.**

Comment: `SendBroadcast` is method of the `Context` class ... `Context` has to be initialized by OS

Comment: also `Java.IO.File` takes **path** as contructor argument, **not URI** ...

Comment: I've fixed with: Android.App.Application.Context.SendBroadCast(MediaScanIntent);

Comment: You could post your solution and accept it, which will help more people .